# Reading .tsv file in Java

Tags: java, csv

I am a beginner and I am trying to read a .tsv data in Java and save the lines to an ArrayList. I wrote a method for it but the only thing I get is line id's and nothing more... I can't find an error. Could you please help me?

```
public static ArrayList<String[]> tsvr(File test2) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader TSVReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(test2));
    String line = TSVReader.readLine();
    ArrayList<String[]> Data = new ArrayList<>(); //initializing a new ArrayList out of String[]'s
    try {
        while (line != null) {
            String[] lineItems = line.split("\n"); //splitting the line and adding its items in String[]
            Data.add(lineItems); //adding the splitted line array to the ArrayList
            line = TSVReader.readLine();
        } TSVReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
    }
    return Data;
}
```

Comment: Please follow javas naming conventions. use `camelCase` for variable names, not `PascalCase`. As you see, SOs syntax highlighting already got confused and marked them as classes instead of variables.

Comment: By the way, for real work (as opposed to practice/learning), use a library to perform the grunt work of reading the tab-delimited file. For example, *Apache Commons CSV*. You can find source-code for entire example apps on other Questions in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you should move `readLine` to a while, so that you can read all the lines of the file. Then you should split the line by tab `\t` because it is a tab separated file

```
public static ArrayList<String[]> tsvr(File test2) {
    ArrayList<String[]> Data = new ArrayList<>(); //initializing a new ArrayList out of String[]'s
    try (BufferedReader TSVReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(test2))) {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = TSVReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] lineItems = line.split("\t"); //splitting the line and adding its items in String[]
            Data.add(lineItems); //adding the splitted line array to the ArrayList
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
    }
    return Data;
}
```

If you want to print the list of array:

```
Data.forEach(array -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But how do I print the file? With "sout" I see only this: [[Ljava.lang.String;@2d209079, [Ljava.lang.String;@6bdf28bb, [Ljava.lang.String;@6b71769e, [Ljava.lang.String;@2752f6e2, [Ljava.lang.String;@e580929, [Ljava.lang.String;@1cd072a9]

Comment: @ta4le Please post this as a new question instead.

Comment: I updated the answer, you can see now how to print the list of array of strings

Comment: @Zabuza ah I see!!! It is an array of string, not a single string. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking on the accept icon if my answer has been helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

### Explanation

- You have to split on `\t` (tab) instead of `\n` (newline). As your `line`s are already single lines, not multiple.
- Another issue in your code is that you close your stream manually, this is unsafe and will create a resource leak in exception-case. You may use try-with-resources to close it safely.

---

### NIO

Instead of fixing your existing code which other answers already did, may I suggest a more compact and possibly more readable version that uses NIO (Java 8 or newer) which does the same:

```
return Files.lines(file.toPath())
    .map(line -> line.split("\t"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you can modernize your method parameters, I would suggest to make it `Path path` instead of `File file`, then you can simply do `Files.lines(path)`

Comment: Thank you so much! The task was a bit different but Ill definitely try out your method sometime!